# TileMap ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a TileMap but when I go to render the tileMap and iterate through all the integers in my map I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Here is the render method:

```
public void render(Renderer renderer) {

    for (int x = 0; x < map[1].length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < map[0].length; y++) {

            if (map[y][x] == -1) {
                continue;
            }

            renderer.getGraphics().drawImage(tileSet.get(map[y][x]).getTexture(), (x * tileSize) + xOffs, (y * tileSize) + yOffs, null);
        }   
    }
}
```

This is the map:

```
map = new int[][] {
    {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
    { 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1},
    { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
};
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at game.TileMap.render(TileMap.java:37)
at game.Main.render(Main.java:57)
at engine.GameLoop.render(GameLoop.java:87)
at engine.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:66)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I believe you swapped x and y in your array.  Try changing `map[y][x]` to `map[x][y]` in all occurrences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your columns and rows reversed...

Based on your code, particularly this statement `if(map[y][x] == -1)` means that you want `y` to be the row index and `x` to be the column index, however your loops are incorrect and both `x` and `y` count the columns. That is why you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because there are more columns than rows and you are attempting to access rows that don't exist.

For a 2D array (matrix), when you say

```
map[i].length
```

You are getting the number of columns of the i-th row of the matrix

To get the number of rows, you should say:

```
map.length
```

Here is a more graphical explanation:

```
//rows     map[row][0],  map[row][1]  map[row][2] 
map[0]  {        A,          0,            0        }
map[1]  {        0,          0,            B        }
map[2]  {        0,          C,            0        }
map[3]  {        D,          0,            0        }
```

The number of rows of this matrix is 4 so `map.length == 4`

The number of columns of this matrix is 3 so `map[0].length == 3`

Now the values `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`. Remember that arrays are zero-indexed.

So, `A` would be at row 0, column 0

```
map[0][0]; // this gives 'A'
```

`B` would be at row 1, column 2

```
map[1][2]; // this gives 'B'
```

`C` would we at row 2, column 1

```
map[2][1]; // this gives 'C'
```

`D` would be at row 3, column 0

```
map[3][0]; // this gives 'D'
```

Furthermore, to have `x` be the row index and `y` be the column index, you should swap the positions of `x` and `y` when you are accessing the map (`map[y][x]` should be `map[x][y]`) throughout your code...

your loop should look like:

```
for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {   // use map.length here for rows
    for (int y = 0; y < map[0].length; y++) {  // use map[0].length here for columns
        if (map[x][y] == -1) {   // use x for rows and y for columns
            continue;
        }
        renderer.getGraphics().drawImage(tileSet.get(map[x][y]).getTexture(), (x * tileSize) + xOffs, (y * tileSize) + yOffs, null);
     }
}
```

**Note:**

Since you have equal amount of columns, it is ok to use `map[0].length` for the number of columns. However, if your number of columns varies, you should use `map[rowIndex].length` to get the number of columns for that specific row.

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over the arrays incorrectly. `map[0].length` and `map[1].length` resolves to 15 because:

```
map[0] == {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}
map[1] == {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

Hence, you get the exception at `map[y][x]` when `y` is 3 (or larger). This is because you try to access the array at `map[3]`, but it contains only 3 elements (arrays are zero based, as you seem to know).

By debugging I am sure you can figure out why you get the exception, and initialize the loop correctly. Hint is that map is actually an array of arrays, meaning that `map[i]` returns the array at index `i`, as per above.